# std::transform and contiguous memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, execution

I need a lambda that applies the (negative) discrete Laplace operator (matrix) to a contiguous memory container (vector) like `std::array` or `std::vector`

[image: Discrete Laplace Operator]

Can it be undefined behavior to write it using `std::transform` incrementing and decrementing pointers like this?

```cpp
  auto A = [n,&h2](const auto & in, auto & out)
  {
    // First line of the matrix
    out[0] = (2.*in[0] - in[1])/h2 ;
    // Middle lines of the matrix
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
                   std::next(in.cbegin()),std::next(in.cend(),-1),std::next(out.begin()),
                   [&h2](const auto & val)
                   {
                     return (-*(std::next(&val,-1)) + 2.*val - *(std::next(&val)))/h2;
                   });
    // Final line of the matrix
    out[n-1] = (-in[n-2] + 2.*in[n-1])/h2;
  };
```

In other words, can algorithms like `for_each` and `transform` and other parallel algorithms break contiguous memory for some execution policy?

**Edit 1**: Note that I don't care which element of the vector `in` I am processing first, what I do care is if when I do `*std::next(&val)` inside the lambda in `std::transform` I do obtain the next element in the vector `in` and not something undefined.

**Edit 2:** I'm thinking of policies that would imply copying values somewhere else (for instance a SIMD register) and execute the lambda there before bringing back the result. Is there a condition in the standard on the execution policy or on the parallel algorithm that prevents that?

Comment: See the **Notes** section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. This relates to which element is processed first though, which is definitely not a problem for a matrix-vector multiplication. The question is if I am, for instance, processing element 42 inside ```std::transform```, would I always obtain element 41 by decrementing the pointer to 42 and, conversely, element 43 by incrementing the pointer to 42?

Comment: Thank you @Artyer So that means that an execution policy can't be, for instance, copy a chunk of the values somewhere else, use the lambda over the copied values and then bring the values back? I'm thinking of SIMD policies for instance.

Comment: I can't find in the standard if there is a requirement on ```std::transform``` or on the execution policy that the argument of the lambda, when passed by reference, must be a reference to the exact element of the input vector.

Comment: @Artyer That's exactly what I am interested in. Something in the standard that would prevent ```val``` from being a reference to a **copy** of the actual value in the vector. I need this before using this in production code.

Comment: I know that the developers of ```std::experimental::simd``` wanted to create an execution policy for SIMD parallelism that would be completely transparent. I'm afraid they'd copy chunks of the vector to a SIMD register before applying the lambda and then ```std::next``` would fall out of bounds. Is it disallowed by the standard?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not safe [[algorithms.parallel.exec]p3](https://wg21.link/algorithms.parallel#exec-3):

> Unless otherwise stated, implementations may make arbitrary copies of elements (with type `T`) from sequences where `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` and `is_trivially_destructible_v<T>` are true.

The solution given in the notes is to wrap the iterators:

```cpp
auto ptr_view = in | std::views::transform([](const auto& i) { return &i; });
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
      std::next(ptr_view.begin()),std::prev(ptr_view.end()),std::next(out.begin()),
      [&h2](auto* ptr)
      {
        return (-ptr[-1] + 2.*ptr[0] - ptr[1])/h2;
      });
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I'll double check your implementation shortly on my code and approve your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Although very compact, the solution using std::cref and the std::reference_wrapper instances that it creates seems likely to frustrate the optimizations that https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-3 seeks to facilitate.

Comment: @Artyer and @Astor, is there any material difference between `-*(std::next(&val,-1)) + 2.*val - *(std::next(&val)))/h2` and `(-*(&val-1) + 2.*val - *(&val+1))/h2`?  If not, is there any reason why you have chosen the more complicated version?

Comment: @Jonno I just copied it from the question but have since changed it

Comment: @Artyer Sorry for the late reply. The code is not working, here's a test in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/n8b5bze4f  My code works as shown by the norm of the approximate solution being similar to the exact solution and the norm of the residual being small. I left your code commented, if you switch, you'll see it doesn't work for some reason. I'm looking on my side as well what could be going wrong, but I'm not well versed in ranges-fu, so it might take me some time.

Comment: @Artyer @Jonno What do you think about this?
```
    auto const in2 = in | std::views::slide(3);
    std::transform(execPol,
          in2.cbegin(),in2.cend(),std::next(out.begin()),
          [&h2](const auto & val)
          {
            return (-val[0] + 2.*val[1] - val[2])/h2;
          });
```

Comment: @Artyer and @Astor, it turns out that `auto ptr_view = in | std::views::transform([](const auto& i) { return &i; });` produces an input range, so `ptr_view.end()` only meets the requirements of _LegacyInputIterator_.  `prev(i)` requires that `i` meets the requirements of _LegacyBidirectionalIterator and so `prev(ptr_view.end())` hangs, at least on my computer.  It's easy to see why `std::views::transform` returns an input range.  If the work is broken up, lists are much easier to join than vectors.

Comment: @Artyer and @Astor, I think `std::views::slide` is a great idea -- and seems to work on my computer.  But the big question is, how big is N going to be?  If it is only of the order of 10, then I very much doubt that there will be much to gain by having `std::transform` distribute the work over multiple threads.  A possible improvement might be to combine the processing in `A`, `rhs_i - A_i` and `x_i + d*res_i` into a single lambda expression, which would divide the number of thread initiations and joins by 3.

Comment: @Jonno @Artyer N is suppossed to be very big. I did the least of the job, I think that if @Artyer would modify his solution to use ```std::views::slide``` then I can accept his answer since he found what the standard says.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the solution proposed by @Artyer, I propose the following solution based on a custom iterator.  The language lawyers may have a better way of defining the iterator and I will bow to their superior knowledge if that is the case.

The primary advantage of the custom iterator is that it facilitates the making of arbitrary copies of elements as foreseen by [algorithms.parallel.exec, p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-3), and may as a consequence (depending on the hardware and compiler) execute faster on large vectors.

Additionally, I considered `(-*(std::next(&val,-1)) + 2.*val - *(std::next(&val)))/h2` to be somewhat undesirable on account of it creating a kind of hidden coupling between the lambda expression in the call to `std::transform` and the structure of the container that is passed to `A`.

If nothing else, you could use the algorithm below as a testing control to verify that the solution proposed by @Artyer functions and performs as expected.

```
    auto A = [n,&h2](const auto & in, auto & out)
    {
        using TheirIter = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(in)>
            ::type::const_iterator;
        using ValueType = typename TheirIter::value_type;

        struct Slider {
            ValueType x_2, x_1, x_0;
        };

        class MyIter {
            TheirIter iter, end;
            Slider slider;
        public:
            typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef Slider value_type;
            typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            typedef const Slider* pointer;
            typedef const Slider& reference;

            explicit MyIter(TheirIter _iter, TheirIter _end) :
                iter{_iter}, end{_iter},
                slider {*std::next(_iter,-2), *std::next(_iter,-1), *_iter} {}
            MyIter& operator++() { ++iter;
                slider.x_2 = slider.x_1;
                slider.x_1 = slider.x_0;
                slider.x_0 = iter != end ? *iter : 0;
                return *this; }
            MyIter operator++(int) { MyIter retval = *this; ++(*this);
                return retval; }
            bool operator==(MyIter other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
            bool operator!=(MyIter other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
            reference operator* () const { return slider; }
        };

        // First line of the matrix
        out[0] = (2.*in[0] - in[1])/h2 ;
        // Middle lines of the matrix
        std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
            MyIter (std::next(in.cbegin(),2), in.cend()),
            MyIter (in.cend(), in.cend()),
            std::next(out.begin()),
            [&h2](const auto & val)
            {
                 return (-val.x_2 + 2*val.x_1 - val.x_0)/h2;
            });
        // Final line of the matrix
        out[n-1] = (-in[n-2] + 2.*in[n-1])/h2;
    };
```